# Is it possible to step into the expanded Macro when use CLion debugging Rust project

Tags: rust, clion, jetbrains-ide

In Rust IDE CLion, Now, when debugging step by step, if the code is a piece of Macro. CLoin will not expand and go into the Macro. The debugging cursor pointed to the code is jumping on the Macro repeatedly. So users can't know the authentic execute code。The ·cargo expand· is like a static tool, but it can't integrate into debugging.

Is it possible to step into the expanded Macro when use CLion debugging rust project.

Make the debugging journey like going through line by line in the expanded Macro happily?

Update 1: CLion will expand the Macro automatically, Is the expanded file cached for compiling? If a bin is debuggable, the bin must have symbol info, Is it possible when do step debugging, tools like CLion, gdb or lldb can point the current debugging line to the expanded file or the raw source code file(option by user) by finding clue the symbol?

Update 2: Sometimes, My program got a panic. From the stacktrace, I got a file named like '/sfwerasdf2323r.rs', I opened it in the editor, I think it's an auto-expanded file by CLion. I tried to "open in" from the context menu of the file to find it out in the `File explorer`(or `Finder`), but CLion shows: `open in -> nowhere`. Is this file a cache in memory? Is it not in a `/tmp` folder?

This makes me believe that it is possible to debug in the expanded file. CLion maybe need to do a further more is to format the auto-expanded file

Comment: This was previously an answer but as pointed out by @Chayim Friedman, the output of `cargo expand` is not necessarily reproducible. Still, you can *try* to replicate the macro behavior by inserting the code expansion and fixing any compilation errors. You might end up with code that does not behave the same as the macro, but as a debugging tool it might be worth to check out.

Comment: Could you please give a link to the previously answer? I think the none-reproducible code is not a big deal, keep the expanded code when generating the bin. If debugging, use the cached file to refer as source code. we just want the match of the bin and the source code. when compile second time, get the next version of the expanded code, only care about they are matched.

Comment: I deleted it after it received a downvote and an explanation why it can be unreliable. In retrospect adding a disclaimer would've probably been the right course of action. Were you able to step into the code using the `cargo expand` output?

Comment: What you deleted? `cargo expand` is difficult for beginner because it has to fix a lot of compile error, reorg many imports. A simple debug way is a big help for beginner.